# Parameters that affect performance of web app on different clients

Tags: performance, server

I have built a web application, in which I display a map and I use both WMS and WFS requests in order to show network (lines) and points of interest on the map. The application has several filters in order to send queries to database (such as date filters etc.).

The app runs in a remote server. The speed when accessing the app from my browser (firefox or chrome) is satisfying. Everything runs quite smoothly.

My issue is that I get complaints related to speed and performance. So my question is: on what does the performance depends on and how can it be possible that me having great experience and others don't?

One hypothesis is that the computer power of the other client is too low (which is not the case).
Another one is that the server doesn't have enough resources (which is also not the case). 
What are other parameters that affect the performance of a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection speed is a very important factor and also the response time (mostly distance client-server).

Comment: You mean the physical location between the client and the server. In this case that would make sense as the client is located in The Netherlands and the server in south europe. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's basically right. The response time can also depend on the kind of connection everyone is using, e.g. you have a very high response time over satellite, while cable is usually faster.